# How to replace every word with another word from a file using awk ( the words are given as command line parameters in awk)

Tags: bash, awk

I did something like this but nothing is printing

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo 'There are no words'
        exit 1
fi
echo | awk 'BEGIN {gsub(/ARGV[1]/,"ARGV[2]");  print}' $@
```

I think it is because I don't have the file specified but how can I specify it if I already read the words from the command line input in awk

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
        echo "usage: $0 str1 str2 file [file...]"
        exit 1
fi
exec awk 'BEGIN {s=ARGV[1]; r=ARGV[2]; delete ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[2]} {gsub(s,r);  print}' "$@"
```

if you are using the arguments to `awk` that are not filenames you have to remove them.

Comment: I think it should be ```{gsub(s,r); print}``` so that it reads s  as a variable and it works perfectly

Comment: @RobertChrisstian my bad, I should have removed the `/`. Corrected.